# Customize Ag-Grid Status Bar

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

We have been Ag-Grid Enterprise, Version 19("ag-grid-angular": "19.0.0", "ag-grid-community": "19.0.0", "ag-grid-enterprise": "19.0.0") with Angular 4.
We have a requirement where we need to customize the status bar of the grid and add one more icon to the status bar to achieve some functionality.
The link "https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-status-bar-component/" says this is possible but when trying to implement, we are unable to fine any interfaces by the name "IStatusBarItem" and "IStatusBarItemParams" under module "ag-grid-community" and hence stuck with the implementation.
Any help on what we might be missing here?

Comment: I just opened an issue on Github. https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2920

Answer (score 1):

Just for someone who will face same issue: you should use IStatusPanel and IStatusPanelParams instead of IStatusBarItem and IStatusBarItemParams in versions 19 and 20 of ag-grid